# Issue with filtering an Angular Table td

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table created in angularJS.

HTML:

```
<div class="widget-content" ng-controller="getAllBenchersController">
    <table ng-table="talentPoolList" show-filter="true"
            class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr ng-repeat="employee in $data" | filter: testFilter">
            <td data-title="'#'">{{$index + 1}}</td>
            <td data-title="'Employee ID'" sortable="'employee.employeeNo'"
                    filter="{ 'employee.employeeNo': 'text' }">
                {{employee.employee.employeeNo}}
            </td>
            <td data-title="'Current State'" sortable="'state.state'" filter="{ 'state.state': 'text' }" 
                    ng-class="{ red: employee.state.state == 'Available', blue: employee.state.state == 'Blocked'}">
                {{employee.state.state}}            
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

In the `<td data-title="'Current State'">`I want to apply a filter. I want to display only states returning values 'Available' and 'Blocked'.

My controller is :

```
myApp.controller('getAllBenchersController', ['$scope', 'employeeTalentPoolServices', 'dataTable', '$window', '$timeout', function ($scope, employeeTalentPoolServices, dataTable, $window, $timeout) {
    employeeTalentPoolServices.getAllBenchers().then(function (result) {
        $scope.data = result.data;
 $scope.testFilter = function (item) {
            return (item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'available' || item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'blocked');
        }
});
```

The states generally return values -'Available', 'Blocked', 'Billed' and 'Rejected'. I want the table to only display states - 'Available' and 'Blocked'.
Please have a check and point out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to display only the items with the state 'available' and 'blocked' i think the best choice is to apply an angular filter in the ng-repeat. By this way, the ng-repeat only computes the items needed for the table.

You can add a new filter, for example:

```
myApp.filter('filterState',
  [], function() {
      return function(items) {
        return items.map(function(obj) {
          if (obj.state === 'available' || obj.state === 'blocked')
             return obj;
        });
});
```

After, your div element should be:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in $data" | filter: filterState">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return (item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'available' || item.state.state.toLowerCase() === 'blocked');
```

Above code returns a boolean value, also if you have array list of values , here only one value is considered. 
You should write a for loop , then check the values.
Refer below code:

```
var filteredOutput=[];
for(var i=0;i<item.length; i++){
if(item[i].state.state.toLowerCase() === 'available' || item[i].state.state.toLowerCase() === 'blocked')
  {
    filteredOutput.push(item[i]);
  } 
}
return filteredOutput;
```